# how to update values in codeigniter rest for web service

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi all am using the following code

```
function update_profile_post()  {
    $serviceName = 'update_profile';
    //getting posted values
    $ip['user_id'] = trim($this->input->post('user_id'));
    $ip['firstname'] = trim($this->input->post('firstname'));
    $ip['lastname'] = trim($this->input->post('lastname'));
    $ip['city'] = trim($this->input->post('city'));
    $ip['state'] = trim($this->input->post('state'));
    $ip['address'] = trim($this->input->post('address'));
    $ip['phone_number'] = trim($this->input->post('phone_number'));
    $ip['is_pic_changed'] = trim($this->input->post('is_pic_changed'));

    $ipJson = json_encode($ip);
    //validation
    $ip_array[] = array("user_id", $ip['user_id'], "not_null", "user_id", "User ID is empty."); 
    $ip_array[] = array("firstname", $ip['firstname'], "not_null", "Firstname", "Firstname is empty."); 
    $ip_array[] = array("lastname", $ip['lastname'], "not_null", "lastname", "Lastname is empty.");
    $ip_array[] = array("city", $ip['city'], "not_null", "city", "City is empty.");
    $ip_array[] = array("state", $ip['state'], "not_null", "state", "State is empty.");
    $validation_array = $this->validator->validate($ip_array);
    print_r ($validation_array);
    if ($validation_array !=1) {
        $data['message'] = $validation_array;
        $retVals = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
    } 
    if ($ip['is_pic_changed'] == '1') {
        $this->load->library('uploader');
        $uploadPhoto = $this->uploader->upload_image($_FILES['profile_pic'], $ip);
        if ($uploadPhoto == 'failed') {
            $data['message'] = 'Upload failed. Please try again';
            $retVals = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        } else {
            $retVals = $this->user_model->user_update_profile_pic($ip, $uploadPhoto,$serviceName);
        }
    } 
    else{
        $retVals = $this->user_model->user_update_profile($ip, $serviceName);
    }

    header("content-type: application/json");
    echo $retVals;
    exit;
}
```

model

```
function user_update_profile($input, $serviceName){
        $ipJson = json_encode($input);
        $updateArray = array(
            'user_id' => $input['user_id'],
            'firstname' => $input['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $input['lastname'],
            'address' => $input['address'],
            'city' => $input['city'],
            'state' => $input['state'],
            'phone_number' => $input['phone_number'],
            'user_modified_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        );
        $this->db->where('user_id', $input['user_id']);
        $update = $this->db->update('users', $updateArray);
        if ($update) {
            $data['message'] = 'User profile updated Successfully.';
            $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        } else {
            $data['message'] = 'Error In Updating user profile';
            $status = $this->clamo_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        }
        return $status;
    }
```

here the issue is it is directly giving message updated successfully but when we are checking in db it is having all values as null what was the reason for what was wrong am doing. thanks

Comment: Take a look in your user model (the user_update_profile method). It's hard to say what's wrong, since you didn't provide this code.

Comment: i have added model code also

Comment: @user2739848:- Print your mysql query after $update = $this->db->update('users', $updateArray); in model using $this->db->last_query() to get what query is executeing. I think might have your query get blank values